# about php setcookie

Tags: php

I have one problem about php setcookie.
When user upload file in my server, it will set the cookie to store the filename.
setcookie("user", $filename, time()+3600);

In output code:
You recently uploaded:
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
Example: You recently uploaded images: abc.zip

But when user upload the new file,
the new filename will cover the old filename.
how can i do that. Dont cover the old filename.
Example: 
You recently uploaded images: 
abc.zip
def.zip
ghi.zip
.........
.........

Thank!

Comment: You should probably store it in a session rather than a cookie, and just use an array instead of a string.

Comment: Agree with Corbin +1.  The only reason to store in a cookie is if you wanted to persist across sessions.

Comment: @heyman questions are marked as answered by checking the tick sign next to the answer that was most useful to you. Feel free to accept an answer and remove "[solved]" from the question title.

Comment: If the question is solved you should not blank it and put [solved] in the title! Instead, accept an answer below by clicking on the tick by the best answer. I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 3):

Save filenames in a serializable array structure, like a JSON array:

```
$files = !empty($_COOKIE['user']) ? json_decode($_COOKIE['user'], true) : array();
$files[] = $filename;
setcookie('user', json_encode($files), time()+3600);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can append the cookie per upload, with ending special char like that "|" and split when you write the screen.

```
$uploaded = isset($_COOKIE['uploaded']) ? $_COOKIE['uploaded'] : '';
setCookie('uploaded', $uploaded . '|' . $newFileName,time()+3600);

// when showing

$uploaded = explode('|', $_COOKIE['uploaded']);

foreach ($uploaded as $file) {
    if(empty($file)) continue;
    echo $file . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, try this:

```
$old_cookie = $_COOKIE["user"];
setcookie("user", $filename+"<br />"+$old_cookie, time()+3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save you files names into an array :

```
  setcookie("cookie[".$i"."]", $filename);
```

And then :

```
  if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
   foreach ($_COOKIE['cookie'] as $name => $value) {
     $number = htmlspecialchars($name);
     $name = htmlspecialchars($value);        
     echo "File number $number : $value <br />\n";
    }
  }
```

And you get this output:

```
You recently uploaded images: 
File 1: abc.zip
File 2: def.zip
File 3: ghi.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). I find it simpler than directly using cookies.

```
//Start the session
session_start();

//Save the uploaded filename
$_SESSION["uploaded"][] = $filename;

//Show uploaded files
foreach($_SESSION["uploaded"] as $filename)
{
    echo $filename."<br />";
}
```